# How to layout widgets adjacent to each other, but with overlap

Tags: flutter, layout, user-experience

I have been messing around with `Stack` because `Column` doesn't allow the children widgets to be overlapped. However, every example I saw where widgets can be laid out adjacent to each other require hardcoded width and height.

[image: layout example]

In my layout, the height of the children is dependent upon the content of the children, and not known while in my `build` function. Ideally, I would like to layout my widgets using `Column` and use a negative top margin on the green and blue containers, however this is not allowed. Absolutely positioning them would not be difficult if I knew the rendered height of each widget, but that does not seem possible.

There is a nice library from Marc Glasberg called [assorted_layout_widgets](https://github.com/marcglasberg/assorted_layout_widgets) which has a `ColumnSuper` widget which allows for overlapping columns, but it applies to all children the same.

Interested in ideas that others may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can try is using [`FractionalTranslation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionalTranslation-class.html) to move the child by a fraction of its size. Or [`Transform.translate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html) to move the child by a hardcoded distance. These do not require the child to have a hardcoded size.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0, 0.2),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(1),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 80,
          color: Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.7),
        ),
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -10),
          child: Container(
            width: 500,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.7),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

*Edit:*

To have the red box on top of the green box, we can do something like this.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0, 1),
          child: Container(
            width: 500,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.7),
          ),
        ),
        FractionalTranslation(
          translation: Offset(0, -0.8),
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
          ),
        ),
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -10),
          child: Container(
            width: 500,
            height: 80,
            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.7),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: That is very close to what I want to achieve, and I accept the answer. However, the red box is supposed to be on top of the green box, and I don't see any way to make that happen with a translation of the other children.

Comment: One way this can be done is by reversing the order of green and red boxes and then moving them accordingly using translation. I'll edit the answer to include this part.

Comment: Brilliant answer, saved me from custom painters mess to achieve that